# ACS714 5A AC Current Sensing arduino

Tags: arduino, voltage, current, ac, current-measurement

hey guys i just got my ACS714 -5 to +5A IC i am new the current and voltage sensing i googled for tutorials on ACS714 5A but couldn't find a suitable tutorial with AC sensing. 
I got the code below from the arduino playground but the output of the current is not proper. The Curernt reading while the switch is on or off is same. can some help us out.

[Arduino Current Sensing Source](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/CurrentSensing)

```
int AnalogInputPin = 0; // Define analog input pin
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
  double Current = currentSensor(analogRead(AnalogInputPin));  // Read  analog value
  Serial.print(", VariationFromNull: "); 
  printDouble(Current, 2);                                     // display Current
  Serial.print(" A");
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Print decimal numbers
void printDouble(double val, byte precision) {
  Serial.print (int(val));                                     // Print int part
  if( precision > 0) {                                         // Print decimal part
    Serial.print(".");
    unsigned long frac, mult = 1;
    byte padding = precision -1;
    while(precision--) mult *=10;
    if(val >= 0) frac = (val - int(val)) * mult; else frac = (int(val) - val) * mult;
    unsigned long frac1 = frac;
    while(frac1 /= 10) padding--;
    while(padding--) Serial.print("0");
    Serial.print(frac,DEC) ;
  }
}
// Read 1.1V reference against AVcc
long readInternalVcc() {
  long result;
  ADMUX = _BV(REFS0) | _BV(MUX3) | _BV(MUX2) | _BV(MUX1);
  delay(2);                                                    // Wait for Vref to settle
  ADCSRA |= _BV(ADSC);                                         // Convert
  while (bit_is_set(ADCSRA,ADSC));
  result = ADCL;
  result |= ADCH<<8;
  result = 1126400L / result;                                  // Back-calculate AVcc in mV
  return result;
}
// Calculate current with Allegro ACS714
double currentSensor(int RawADC) {
  int    Sensitivity    = 185; // mV/A
  long   InternalVcc    = readInternalVcc();
  double ZeroCurrentVcc = InternalVcc / 2;
  double SensedVoltage  = (RawADC * InternalVcc) / 1024;
  double Difference     = SensedVoltage - ZeroCurrentVcc;
  double SensedCurrent  = Difference / Sensitivity;
  Serial.print("ADC: ");
  Serial.print(RawADC);
  Serial.print("/1024");
  Serial.print(", Sensed Voltage: ");
  printDouble(SensedVoltage, 1);
  Serial.print("mV");
  Serial.print(", 0A at: ");
  printDouble(ZeroCurrentVcc, 1);
  Serial.print("mV");
  return SensedCurrent;                                        // Return the Current
}
```

Comment: For a start I'd disconnect the ACS714 from the micro, check ACS714 output with a multimeter and tie the analog to GND followed by say 1.5V to work out if it's a sensor or micro/code problem.

Comment: Yes i tried measuring analog output of ACS714 and am getting varying output from 0.5mA to 0.8mA.

Comment: I've never used a ACS714 but it appears to be a voltage output device from the datasheet, any reason you're trying to measure the current?

Comment: I suspect you are using [Pololu](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1185) break out which as mentioned above is a Voltage output of the current. Use a Multimeter and verify you are getting the expected voltages representing your input. In this case AC. but also check DC, etc...

Comment: Tried every thing till date guess i have a faulty one :(

Comment: This is an forward and reverse DC sensing chip. I would guess it reads 0 for AC current.